# Do the Jews still send a scapegoat once a year to the wilderness?

Tags: halacha, sin, yom-kippur, judaism

Do the Jews still send scapegoats bearing the sins of the Jewish people to the wilderness once a year as commanded in Leviticus 16:22?

Comment: Not since the Temple was destroyed

Comment: Right, it's part of the sacrificial ritual. No Temple, no priestly garments for the priest, we don't do it.

Comment: @Shalom this was done by not-a-priest outside the temple

Comment: But it needs to be selected by a priest alongside the other goat.

Comment: @clint does it? Does he need to be dressed to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Sefer HaChinukh 185](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaChinukh.185?lang=bi):

> The commandment of the service of Yom Kippur: That the high priest do all the procedure of Yom Kippur, with the order of the sacrifices, the confessions, **the sending away of the goat** and the rest of the service, as it is written in the section of the Torah — as it is stated (Leviticus 16:3), “With this shall Aharon enter the Holy, etc.” until the end of the section ...
>
> **And all of this commandment is practiced at the time of the [Temple]**. And now that — due to our iniquities — we have neither a Temple nor a high priest, neither serving garments nor sacrifices, all of Israel has been accustomed to serve on this day though our prayers and supplications. And [it is] as it is written (Hoshea 14:3), “and [instead of] bulls, we shall pay [the offering of] our lips.”
>
> (*translation by R. Francis Nataf, emphases mine*)